# Cortana settings in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Formerly I could type questions in Cortana and the answers would pop up quickly.  Somehow I changed the mode so that a microphone icon appears and the only way to use it is verbally.How do I revert to typing the question and the answer comes from redirection to written replies.  I.E.no mike, no workee!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Cortana
Select Cortana > Make sure Show Search box is checked